# Powershell issue - 32-bit vs 64-bit

Tags: windows, powershell, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, command-prompt

I am having an issue on my machine with PowerShell (x86).  If I type:

```
cmd
```

I get no output.  However, If I type this into 64-bit PowerShell, I get the output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

And idea why this is behaving this way?  It's as if PowerShell (x86) is just not executing this command.  I am running 64-bit Windows 7.

Edit: `cmd` is just an example of what's happening.  It also happens when I want to execute foo.exe in some random folder.  I'm looking for a solution for the general case of running executables in 32-bit PowerShell.

Edit:  In case somebody with the same issue sees this, the way I was able to fix this was by changing my ComSpec environment variable to:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start and open a 32-bit command prompt you need to type:

```
$env:windir\SysWoW64\cmd.exe
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm trying to do.  What I want to know is why `cmd` doesn't work in 32-bit PowerShell, and how I can fix it.

Comment: And `cmd` isn't necessarily the command I want to run - it could be foo.exe in some random folder - the same thing is happening.

Comment: try this in your 32bit powershell session and tell me what returns: `$env:ComSpec`

Comment: I get: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: then you can't run/start a 64bit application from a 32bit shell

Comment: Fair enough, that explains why `cmd` won't work.  However, in my situation, `foo.exe` is a 32bit application and still is not working in PowerShell (x86).  Any idea why?

Comment: a double click on foo.exe what do? foo.exe isn't corrupted? no error shown? Running foo.exe from a 'run as administrator' shell do something different?

Comment: If I double click on it, it opens in the command prompt - which is probably why it won't work since cmd.exe is 64 bit.  I'll have to look into other options - thanks for all the help though.